# What is the PotgreSql equivalent of a mysql query using Sgt_asText(point(longitude, latitude))

Tags: mysql, postgresql, shapes

I would like to use a point with longitude and latitude in the following Postgres query (at the end of post), but I get this error:

```
ERROR:  function st_astext(point) does not exist
LINE 1: ...CONCAT_WS(',', 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(',group_concat(st_asText(...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

SQL query :

```
SELECT ogc_fid, name, CONCAT_WS(',', 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(',group_concat(st_asText(point(longitude, latitude))),',',st_astext(geometry),')') as shape FROM locationshape WHERE locationshape.location_id IS NULL AND st_contains(geometry, point(longitude, latitude));
```

Answer (score 0):

`point()` creates a **point**, i.e. a native postgres type.

`ST_point()` will create a point **geometry**, which is a Postgis type and which can be used in other PostGIS functions such as `st_asText`

```
select st_asText(st_point(1,2));
 st_astext
------------
 POINT(1 2)
(1 row)
```

That being said, you may want to have a look at [`st_collect`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) to create the geometrycollection from geometries, not from text.